# Leaflet circle loop remove past and retain recent iterations

Tags: javascript, dom, leaflet

Good day!

I am trying to play around with animating a pulsating radius based on leaflet L.cicle and have managed to limit the radius size.

However, I am having a problem with several iterations of the radius are not removed from the map, resulting in a large number of circles.

I would appreciate some advice on how to remove the previous iterations of the circle and keep the most recent circle generated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <title>Map</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>


    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #map {
            width: 600px;
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>

    <style>body { padding: 0; margin: 0; } #map { height: 100%; width: 100vw; }</style>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
<div id='map'></div>

<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([1.3400776203517657, 103.88408580637439],6);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1
        
    }).addTo(map);

    function radiuspulse() {
        const secs = 0.1 * 60;
        let radiuschange = 0;
        setInterval(function() {
            if (radiuschange < 50000) {
                radiuschange += 500;
                const circle = L.circle([1.3400776203517657, 103.88408580637439], {
                color: 'red',
                fillColor: '#f03',
                fillOpacity: 0.1,
                weight:0,
                id: 'abc123',
                radius: radiuschange
                }).addTo(map);
                function clearcontent() {
                    document.getElementsByTagName("g").innerHTML = "";
                };
            }
            else {
                // clearInterval();
                let radiuschange = 0;
                radiuspulse();
            }
        }, secs);
        
    }

    radiuspulse()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create always a new Circle, change only the radius with `setRadius()`:

Also you can remove the circle with `circle.removeFrom(map)`

```
var circle = L.circle([1.3400776203517657, 103.88408580637439], {
        color: 'red',
        fillColor: '#f03',
        fillOpacity: 0.1,
        weight:0,
        id: 'abc123',
        radius: 500
      }).addTo(map);

      var interval = null;
      function radiuspulse() {
        const secs = 0.1 * 60;
        let radiuschange = circle.getRadius();
        interval = setInterval(function() {
          if (radiuschange < 50000) {
            radiuschange += 500;
            circle.setRadius(radiuschange);
          }
          else {
            clearInterval(interval);
            circle.setRadius(0);
            radiuspulse();
          }
        }, secs);
      }

      function clearcontent() {
        circle.removeFrom(map);
      }
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you! This is awesome! I've been thinking about it the wrong way.